# C# Assign static dictionary to filtered version of other dictionary in static class

Tags: c#, dictionary, static

I have a class, with some global and constant dictionaries. Like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyDictionary= new Dictionary<string, MyObject>()
    {
        {"first", new MyObject()},
        {"second", new MyObject()},
    };
}
```

Lets say I would like another dictionary, to be like that only with some added and removed elements. Is there a way to achieve that, within the static class? I imagine something like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyOtherDictionary = MyDictionary.Remove("second").Add("Third", new MyObject())
```

But I know that does not work, so is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool`, you can't use `Add` on a bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesnt work in this way for two reasons:

1. [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool`, you can't use `Add` on a bool
2. even if you make it compile, you don't want to modify the other dictionary but you want to create a new dictionary which contains similar items, you can use the constructor:

---

```
public static Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyOtherDictionary;
// ...
static Constants
{
    MyOtherDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>(MyDictionary);
    MyOtherDictionary.Remove("second");
    MyOtherDictionary.Add("Third", new MyObject());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using properties instead

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<string, MyObject> myDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, MyObject>()
            {
                { "first",  new MyObject()},
                { "second", new MyObject()},
            };
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, MyObject> _myOtherDictionary;
    public static Dictionary<string, MyObject> myOtherDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            _myOtherDictionary = myDictionary;
            _myOtherDictionary.Remove("first");
            _myOtherDictionary.Add("third", new MyObject());
            return _myOtherDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```